# Jquery and formating a textarea for tagging?

Tags: jquery, tags, textarea, tagging

I am looking for a way to use a textarea and get the values separated by commas, and place them into the array.

Really I am looking for how to auto format the textarea so when the user types something in it either forces or something a comma break. I want to use autocomplete, but I have no data to check it with since this will be a new user sign up.

What's the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = $('#mytextarea').val().split(" ");
```

Comment: Just about to post that but shouldn't it be split(",")?

Comment: and then use text=text.join(",");

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [plugin](http://loopj.com/2009/04/25/jquery-plugin-tokenizing-autocomplete-text-entry/) to enforce seperation of item in textarea

Comment: This is really nice, just I do not have data to pull from, and what if a user needed to create a new value?